# conda `ResolvePackageNotFound` after fresh install

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

## I want to create a new conda environment.

However, I get the following error message:

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ conda env create -n ml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - libspatialindex==1.9.0=h6de7cb9_1
  - libgdal==2.4.0=h89caebc_1002
  - gdal==2.4.0=py37h0e3174d_1002
  - openblas==0.3.5=h436c29b_1001
  - libcxxabi==8.0.0=2
```

I removed all of my old environments (they had become bloated) and uninstalled and reinstalled a new miniconda3 installation.

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/tommylees/miniconda3
```

Here is some other information:

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/tommylees/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/tommylees/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.8.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.15.7=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /Users/tommylees/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/tommylees/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/tommylees/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/tommylees/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/tommylees/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.6 Darwin/19.6.0 OSX/10.15.7
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

(base) ➜  ~ cat /Users/tommylees/.condarc
cat: /Users/tommylees/.condarc: No such file or directory

(base) ➜  ~ ls /Users/tommylees/.conda/envs
ls: /Users/tommylees/.conda/envs: No such file or directory
```

I do not understand why the conda installer is still looking for gdal or other packages which were previously installed but I thought I had removed.

Comment: You likely need to add the **conda-forge** channel. For example, [`libspatialindex==1.9.0=h6de7cb9_1` is from there](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libspatialindex/files?version=1.9.0).

Comment: Tommy Lee, if this answers your problem, please say so.